# Sqalchemy substituting text with integers

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, associations

I am designing a database using Sqlalchemy for recording lab measurements. I have a table for each test result. I want to store the test result and a name label in the same row. The name labels can occur multiple times, whenever I run the same test. Therefore instead of storing the actual label multiple times I would like to replace each label with an integer. The integer would be a key to another table that just stores the labels.

The database table definitions are as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float ,
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class TestResults(Base):

    __tablename__ = "test_results"


    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    test_name = Column(Integer)  # id value in TestNames table
    timestamp = Column(Integer)
    test_value = Column(Float)


class TestNames(Base):
    """
    Lookup table for test_name column in TestResults

    """
    __tablename__ = 'test_names'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

Ideally I would like to be able to enter the data into the TestResults table by just entering the test_name as a string, e.g.

```
results = TestResults()
results.test_name = 'my_test'
results.test_value = 10.1
```

In order to do this I think I need an intermediate function that checks if the string I enter into results.test_name already exists in the TestNames table, if it does then the 'real' results.test_name is populated with the id number for the existing name. If the name doesn't exist then it is added to TestNames and the id of the new name is populated into results.test_name. The function to do this would be something like this:

```
def test_name_creator(session,name):
    """
    Input
    -------
    session : sqlalchemy session object

    name : str
        New test name


    Output
    --------
    id : int
        id of test name

    """


    # Check if name already exists
    name_query = session.query(TestNames).filter(TestNames.name==name).all()
    if name_query!=[]:
        name_id = name_query[0].id
        return name_id

    # name does not exist, add to TestNames() table
    new_test_name = TestNames()
    new_test_name.name = name
    session.add(new_test_name)
    session.commit()
    return new_test_name.id
```

What I can't get my head around is how to intercept the setting of results.test_name='my_test' with the function above so that the returned id is actually populated into results.test_name. I think this is the job of an association_proxy + creator function, but all the examples that I have seen return Sqlalchemy declarative_base() class objects, not simple integers.

Comment: You should look into foreign keys. It sounds like what you want. Here is a simple foreign key example: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#defining-foreign-keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `test_name_creator` returning the ID, return the instance itself, like this:

```
def test_name_creator(session, name):
    inst = session.query(TestNames).filter(TestNames.name == name).first()
    if inst is None:
        # Create new TestNames() instance and add to database
        inst = TestNames(name=name) 
        session.add(inst)
    return inst
```

Then, set up a relationship so that SQLAlchemy will figure out where to put the IDs:

```
class TestResults(Base):
    ...
    test_name_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(TestNames.id))
    test_name = relationship(TestNames)
```

You set the name like this:

```
results = TestResults(test_name=test_name_creator(session, "my_test"), value=10.1)
```

If you want to keep the usage pattern of having `test_name` as a `string` that you can assign to but create rows in `TestNames`, you can use [association proxies](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) combined with the [UniqueObject](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueObject) recipe.

Comment: Thanks it works. Just need to modify `test_name_creator()` so that it returns new instances of `TestNames` when it creates them.